# Classes 2d lists in python

Tags: python

I have a 2d list and a class to get users input and compare that object to what is stored.

For testing purposes it prints the coordinate and its equal to A but it ignores the if statement by not adding to the count.

Why is it ignoring the if statement

this is my current code

```
count =0
print self.object[row][col]
if self.object[row][col] == "A":
    count +=1
print count
```

Comment: What is the result of `type(self.object[row][col])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about the type of `self.object[row][col]` and type matters, as clearly visible below:

```
>>> 1 == "1"
False
```

Thus, by guessing, you can try the following comparisons, converting your variable into appropriate type before comparison:

- converting to string:

  ```
  if str(self.object[row][col]) == "1":
  ```
- converting to integer:

  ```
  if int(self.object[row][col]) == 1:
  ```

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: im sorry i made a mistake imputing here, it was supposed to be A and not 1 but i really appreciate you having the time and trying to help me anyways i saw in you response what i did wrong